# Get last word position (x,y) coordinates in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to wrap the email addresses inside textarea to the next row rather than breaking.
I have try somehow to find  the last word that reaches the border, but I couldn't find any solution
My question is : Is there any event where I can get the position of the last word reaching the border of the textarea so i can get the last word and move it to the next line?

In the following img you can see the current behavior

[image: textarea example]

Comment: Getting the (X,Y) of text in a textarea is dependent on a lot of things you don't have much control over like font overrides or the current browser zoom level. If your end goal is to control how your email is split in a text area, you can control that with CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: *I want to wrap the email addresses inside textarea to the next row rather than breaking* - how will finding the (x,y) coordinates of the last word help for this?  What is x,y?  character position?  pixels?  Please ask the question for the problem that you want to solve; there seem to be 2 different problems here - get x,y of last word / don't wrap emails.   You'll probably need to use a custom input to handle this sort of thing (rather than textarea).

Comment: Yes, splitting the email is my goal. The thing is I have difficulties in selecting the last email that reaches the border, so I was thinking if there is some event to find the position of the word that reaches the border

Answer (score 0):

If i could understand your question. You can add `<br>` tag before last email it will bring down the last email to next row.
if you want emails in first row to reach border of text area use`<div class="textarea" align="justify"` it will stretch it to the border of the text area.
Please elaborate if i misunderstood your question.

Edit: in `textarea` there's isn't much you can do cause its mostly used for comments section.

Comment: thank you I will give it a try and format the text from the text area and insert in inside a `<div>`